# 2D Numpy Array indexing by using 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

```
  position_array = np.array([[1,2]
                      [0,1]
                      [0,2]])

  original_array = np.array([[5,6,7]
                             [7,8,2]
                             [10,6,2]])

result_i_want = np.array([[6,7]
                        [7,2]
                        [10,2]])
```

how to do this?

get a new array from original_array and use position_array as index ??

for example when the first line of position_array is [1,2] that mean get column 1 and column 2 from the first line of original_array

how to do this simplest way?

Answer (score 2):

You want [`np.take_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html), setting `axis=1`:

```
np.take_along_axis(original_array, position_array, axis=1)

array([[ 6,  7],
       [ 7,  8],
       [10,  2]])
```

---

Or you can also use [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing):

```
original_array[np.arange(original_array.shape[0])[:,None], position_array]

array([[ 6,  7],
       [ 7,  8],
       [10,  2]])
```